# Filtering paths to a specific depth

Tags: grep, sed, rsync, regular-expression

I'm using rsync and the flags `-nPaAXz ~/` to check which files are going to be copied.

This is far too verbose to make any sense of.

How could I filter the output so I view the list of files/folders that are going to be copied to a certain depth, eg:

***1 folder deep***

```
/home/afile
/home/afolder/
/home/anotherfolder/
```

***2 folders deep***

```
/home/afile
/home/afolder/afile
/home/afolder/anotherfile
/home/afolder/afolder/
/home/anotherfolder/afile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command takes each path and truncates it to `n` folders deep (defined in the `\{0,n\}` section of the `sed` command and the `{0,n}` section of the grep command). It's then piped into `uniq` to filter out the duplicates.

`rsync -nPaAXz src_dir dst_dir | sed -n 's@^\(\([^/][^/]*/\)\{0,2\}\).*@\1@p' | uniq`

The same thing can also be achieved using `grep`:

`rsync -nPaAXz src_dir dst_dir | grep -oE "^([^/]+/){0,2}"`

Although the above wont work with `GNU grep` versions `< 2.5.3` due to a [**bug**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/trouble-with-grep-o-regex/8902#8902).

Answer (score 3):

The following grep will restrict rsync's verbose output to a depth of 2 folders:

```
rsync -nPaAXz src_dir dst_dir | grep -E '^/?([^/]+/?){0,2}$'
```

Change the `{0,2}` above to `{0,3}` to filter out 3 folders deep. `{0,4}` will filter out 4 folders deep etc.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I think the perfect solution would have to be more complicated though. With this solution, if a particular folder didn't have any files at the relevant depth or shallower, the path would be filtered out completely by the grep. What you would want is for each path to be truncated to the correct depth, and then not to print any duplicate paths. Would you maybe need to use awk to do that?

Comment: Where in this answer is depth addressed? `{0,2}` would be finding a minimum of none with a maximum of 2 for the pattern `([^/]+/?)`. Genuine question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you just want to filter the output, and you don't actually care about reusing the values in any way. That's easy, then: just grep out lines that contain more slashes than you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -nPaAXz src_dir dst_dir | cut -d "/" -f 1-4 | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

cut removes everything after 4 folders deep paths and awk removes duplicates.