# Trouble with grep -o regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to use a grep command with the --only-matching flag, but it's not behaving as I would expect it to.

This command:

`echo "1/2/3/4/5" | grep -oE "^([^/]+/){0,2}"`

Gives this output:

```
1/2/
3/4/
```

I was expecting just `1/2/`

What's going on..? `3/4/` shouldn't match `"^([^/]+/){0,2}"` because it's not at the beginning of the line..

(*running GNU grep **2.5.1***)

Comment: This gives just `1/2/` for me on Debian Squeeze with `GNU grep 2.6.3`. Maybe you should add some more specific details about your distro and grep version.

Comment: as @Arrowmaster, tested on Ubuntu 10.10, with grep 2.6.3-3

Comment: Tested on `GNU/Linux` with `GNU grep 2.5.1` and showing result as @Acorn .

Comment: Works for me with `GNU grep 2.5.4`

Comment: @ Zarkdav,its not working for me on GNU grep 2.5.4
echo "1/2/3/4/5" | grep -oE "^([^/]+/){0,2}"
1/2/

Comment: @sushanth `1/2/` alone is the correct output, actually!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a [bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=11579) in versions of `GNU Grep` earlier than [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=8a025cf81cdf5c3e809c3ecf0656419a2d596796) (i.e. earlier than `GNU` version `2.5.3`).

Quoting the relevant part of the changelog:

```
Previously failing tests relative to left anchors (^ and \<) and -w should now pass.
```

The [initial commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=13fd3250e8cfd45a3165e03521e616220ee51c43) that described the bug also added a test for it:

```bash
# End of a previous match should not match a "start of ..." expression.
grep_test "word_word/" "word_/" "^word_*" -o
```

Comment: This bug, where `grep -o`/`grep --only-matching` allows a caret to match after the end of a previous match instead of only at beginning of line, is still present in Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: This bug is still present today at the end of 2020, in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.7. That's 9 years, 8 months after this question was posted. This was driving me crazy: surely there can't be a BUG IN GREP??? But alas, there is.