# Behavior of grep -o on OSX

Tags: grep, osx

On Linux, when I do `echo foo | grep -o '^.'` to get the first character, it prints `f` as expected. (I know, `| cut -c1` would probably be faster.)

But on OSX, doing the same results in 3 matches (3 lines):

```
f
o
o
```

WTF? Even without the `-o` option, the color of the output (in my environment) tells me that the whole line matches, instead of just the first character.

Can anybody please enlighten me?

Comment: It's not broken (why would they have a broken version?), it just acts differently. `man grep` tells us it's the BSD version, you most likely have the GNU version on Linux.

Comment: Well, it behaves broken to me? `man grep` also tells us to check `man re_format`, which tells us that `^` at that position should actually match only the beginning of a line.

Comment: At the very least, [when the same behaviour was in GNU grep it was regarded as a bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=11579).

Comment: Notably, the (very old) version of GNU grep OS X used to include did have this bug, so I suppose they've at least preserved that behaviour when they switched to BSD grep.

Comment: Sounds like it's probably this bug: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8902/216323

Answer (score 6):

It's an interesting behavior you've noticed there.

It's wrong to classify it as a "bug" because [POSIX doesn't specify a `-o` option for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). You may not like how it behaves, and I'll agree that it's annoying that BSD and GNU `grep` differ, but this behavior is not actually in conflict with what the BSD manual pages say. If you still say it's a bug, well, you know, that's just, like, [your *opinion*, man](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-just-like-your-opinion-man). :)

Perhaps this alternative presentation will show you why it behaves as it does:

```
$ echo foofoofoo | grep -o foo
foo
foo
foo
```

That is, both BSD `grep` and GNU `grep` show *all* of the matching parts of the line, not just the first one. The difference is that BSD `grep` seems to be implementing that by consuming the matched part and then matching again. When it removes the leading `f` in your example, it finds that the `o` following it matches, too, as does the next one.

One fix for this is to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then say `brew install grep`. This will get you GNU `grep` as `ggrep`, so it doesn't collide with the stock version. GNU `grep` will give the same behavior on my example above, but the two differ for this:

```
 $ echo foofoofoo | ggrep -o ^foo
 foo
```

BSD `grep` will print three `foo`s.

If you replace the stock version with a symlink to `ggrep`, beware that some OS updates will replace it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just use `| cut -c1` in this case. I was just really surprised by this bug.

Comment: There is certainly something *inconsistent* about how BSD implements the `-o` option. Compare  `echo "foo bar" | grep -o '[a-z]*'` and `... | grep -o '[a-z]+'`.